# letsencrypt not working for base domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, virtualhost, lets-encrypt, certbot, centos8

I'm using centos 8, and have installed let's Encrypt certificate that's not working for base (root) domain but working for sub domain. I've checked certificates available for both root and sub domains
Found the following certs:

```
    Certificate Name: teachersbook.pk
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Key Type: XXXXXXXX
    Domains: teachersbook.pk www.teachersbook.pk
    Expiry Date: 2021-12-13 06:54:33+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/teachersbook.pk/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/teachersbook.pk/privkey.pem
```

my VHost configuration is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName teachersbook.pk
    ServerAlias www.teachersbook.pk
    ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/teachersbook.pk/

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/teachersbook.pk-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/teachersbook.pk-access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =teachersbook.pk [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.teachersbook.pk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and my Let's Encrypt SSL file configuration is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName teachersbook.pk
    ServerAlias www.teachersbook.pk
    ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/teachersbook.pk/

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/teachersbook.pk-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/teachersbook.pk-access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/teachersbook.pk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/teachersbook.pk/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: [http://teachersbook.pk base domain](http://teachersbook.pk) redirecting to centos 8 test page but [http://www.teachersbook.pk sub domain](http://www.teachersbook.pk) working fine, [http://teachersbook.pk base domain ](http://teachersbook.pk) is a base domain for that ssl certificate not working

Comment: Your site is not serving a Let's Encrypt certificate. Restart Apache.

Comment: I've already done, that's my problem  Let's Encrypt certificate works for sub domain but not for parent(root) domain. you can check it [subdomain] (https://www.teachersbook.pk/)